# Что пошло не так при установке gulp-uglify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm

Ситуация следующая: клонировал с GitHub Gulp-сборщик (причём не впервые, предыдущие версии устанавливались и запускались на ура), в этом же случае, при выполнении `npm install`, выдаёт ошибку с gulp-uglify:

```js
:~/Dropbox/Projects/Gulp/brandly$ npm i
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! file /home/user/.npm/gulp-uglify/1.5.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /home/user/.npm/gulp-uglify/1.5.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
```

Пробовал уже переустановить Gulp и глобально и локально, всё бестолку. Кто подскажет, в чём тут загвоздка и как её решить?

Comment: Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^

Comment: проблема с package.json. походу он пустой, или есть лишний пробел...

Comment: Удалите файл package.json [stackoverflow.com: Installing Gulp with nvm fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954691/installing-gulp-with-nvm-fails)

Comment: удалить и заново пересоздать?

Comment: Просто удалить.

Comment: проблема не решилась,  если устанавливать все зависимости без gulp-uglify - то все ок становится, а вот команда npm i gulp-uglify выдает ошибку описанную сверху.

Comment: Проблема явно с  package.json( /home/user/.npm/gulp-uglify/1.5.1/package/package.json), там либо нет данных, либо они неверного формата. Если есть возможность, попробуйте где-нибудь найти корректный файл и вставить его перед установкой пакета. Возможно поможет копия данных файла с github'a.

Comment: это понятно, меня другое удивляет: все зависимости устанавливаются без проблем, проблема лишь с gulp-uglify 1.5.1, package.json я удалил, и создал новый при установке npm init

Comment: попробуйте удалить package.json и установить все нужные пакеты самостоятельно с флагом `--save`

Comment: так и сделал, но gulp-uglify поставил предыдущую версию, gulp запустился

Answer (score 1):

Проверте ваш интернет если он слабый то нужно попросить кого то прислать архив в этой сборки. Если лен это делать то можно попробовать `npm cache clean` или  этот код точно не знаю как пишеться, но мне помогло `npm install --registry http://registry.npmjs.org <package name>`